# Implementing Structured Properties in django model

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-nonrel

Google appengine has a model field called Structured Properties which can store a list of models inside another model inside a model. See it here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

What are the ways to implement this in django ? More specifically django-nonrel.

I am currently trying to do this using ListField.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    alist = fields.ListField(models.ForeignKey(ModelA))
```

Is there a better way to do it ?